# Ruby: I need help understanding the following code involving method_missing(method, *args, &block)

Tags: ruby, class, methods, instance-variables, method-missing

I came across this code while trying to learn about creating your own method_missing method, and I don't understand it.
What I don't understand are these parts: method_sym[-1] == "=" and method_sym[0..-2]
What do they refer to? I tried some simulations in irb, but this just returned some weird stuff.

Could anyone break it down for me? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
class UberHash
  def method_missing(method_sym, *args, &block)
    if method_sym[-1] == "="
      instance_variable_set("@#{method_sym[0..-2]}", args[0])
    else
      instance_variable_get("@#{method_sym}")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thats one way to reinvent [openstuct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

Comment: Just had a peak at OpenStruct, looks interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`method_sym`, i.e. the first argument of `method_missing` is the `Symbol` instance representing the name of the method. So, for example, if you call

```
a.foo
```

and Ruby fails to find `foo` method, `a.method_missing(:foo)` will be called.

Next, `Symbol#[]` method is used to return nth character of the symbol or some characters range if you pass `Range` into it. `-1` passed into this method represent "last character". `-2` represents 'the character before the last one' etc. So:

```
symbol = :foo
symbol[-1]
# => "o"
symbol[0..-2]
# => "fo"
```

`args` represents all the arguments passed into missing method. So, if you call your method with:

```
a.foo(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

`args` in `missing_method` will be:

```
[arg1, arg2, arg3]
```

Methods in Ruby can be named with `=` at the end , that's how you create setter methods, like:

```
class A
  def foo=(value)
    @foo = value
  end
end
```

It's regular method and `A.new.foo = some_value` is only a syntactic sugar, under the hood, it's equivalent to `A.new.foo=(some_value)`. So if you call

```
b.foo = 'value'
```

and the `b.foo=` is not defined, Ruby is going to call:

```
b.method_missing(:foo=, 'value')
```

thus the `=` as `method_sym[-1]`.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I didn't get that the first argument of the method_missing (here method_sym) was the first argument of the missing method. In that case, are *args the remaining arguments, or all the arguments (including the first one) ?

Comment: Also, I am still not sure what all this does. For example, why would method_sym[-1] be equal to "=" ?

Comment: @OlivierGirardot I answered to both your questions.

Comment: When you use a splat (`*`) it gathers up the remaining arguments. `**` does the same thing but for keyword arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much! All this is very new to me so I am going to need to study that closely. It is much clearer than before, thanks a lot for your help :)